# How to bulk download files from the internet archive [REVIEW]

Tags: cygwin, emulation, wget, bulkloader

In a previous question I posted very recently on Stack Overflow, [How to bulk download files from the internet archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60881429/how-to-bulk-download-files-from-the-internet-archive), I thought I figured out a way to resolve my problem by using minimal number of commands posted on the [Internet archive help blog](https://blog.archive.org/2012/04/26/downloading-in-bulk-using-wget/), as a reminder, here is their version of commands posted on their blog:

```
wget -r -H -nc -np -nH --cut-dirs=1 -A .pdf,.epub -e robots=off -l1 -i ./itemlist.txt -B 'http://archive.org/download/'
```

against my own version of commands :

```
wget --cut-dirs=1 -A .pdf,.epub -e robots=off -i ./itemlist.txt -B 'http://archive.org/download/'
```

The commands run so well, but I have instead my desired pdf and epub files random numerical file extensions such as:

arxiv-1411.7162
arxiv-1412.0666
arxiv-1410.8703

etc...
After opening these files with a text editor I figured out they were instead html files.
I ran some of these files with a local browser, and a web page indicating the link of my desired PDF download at the bottom of these pages. I want to know how could I extract these files automatically without manual interference, and mention if should I change my previous steps.

Comment: Have you tried using the original command instead of your own, which is clearly broken?